# Why is there serverTimestamp in firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have serverTimestamp in firebase.

I created two documents and tested them.

One is `new Date()` and the other is `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp ()`.

This stored the exact same value.

Nevertheless, why is there a `serverTimestamp`?

I don't mean the `serverTimestamp` that on the **client side (web)**.

I mean the `serverTimestamp` used by **firebase's functions**.

When should I use this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the API documentation for [Timestamp](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Timestamp.html) (I linked to the nodejs server SDK version, which is used by the nodejs Firebase Admin SDK), you'll see that it has a greater granularity than than a [JavaScript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).  Timestamp records times to **nanosecond** precision, while Date just uses **millisecond** precision.  This is how Firestore internally represents its timestamps, and the precision is passed along to clients with this new data type *that loses no data*.

Why is that important?  Well, if you have lots of documents entering a collection over time, the chances of getting a truly unique timestamp number go up if the time is more granular.  Also, if nanosecond precision is what Firestore uses, you might need to match that precision when you do things like pagination that require that you know the value of the sorted field at the last item of the page.  If you don't feed back an appropriately precise value, your paging could be inaccurate.

`FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` is important, in particular, because it uses a clock value that's guaranteed to be accurate by Google standards on their own servers.  This uses a very sophisticated way of [dealing with problematic timestamps](https://developers.google.com/time/smear), in particular, dealing with leap seconds.  If a client tries to add a value with its own sense of time, who knows if that client clock value is accurate.  It could be wildly inaccurate, and maybe the developer doesn't want that.  Using `serverTimestamp()` tells Google that it should use its own sense of clock time to be accurate when the client might not be.

You can go even further with this, using [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) that can check to make sure that the web or mobile client provided a `serverTimestamp()` token value in a field value where it should be required, so it can't fake the a timestamp where only the true current timestamp is required.  The security rules language lets you use [request.time](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#time) to compare against a field value to make sure time-based requests are handled correctly.

There might be other ways that the difference in precision makes a difference, but the bottom line is that the client SDKs need to match what the service uses internally.